# Borrar los eventos del elemento document

Tags: javascript

Tengo varios listeners. Cada vez que se ejecuta mi fichero con este código, queda escuchando y se ejecuta n veces, según las n veces que use el fichero .js. quisiera eliminar todos los eventos para que solo funcione una sola vez.

```
 document.addEventListener("clmtrackrNotFound", function(event) {
        //bla bla
    }, false);

   // detect if tracker loses tracking of face
    document.addEventListener("clmtrackrLost", function(event) {
        //bla bla
    }, false);

    // detect if tracker has converged
    document.addEventListener("clmtrackrConverged", function(event ) {
   },false);
```

Cómo puedo eliminar todos los eventos de escucha el elemento dom?

esto estoy haciendo según la respuesta de @sakulino

```
     function fn_clmtrackrConverged(event) {
      event.target.removeEventListener(event.type, "fn_clmtrackrConverged");
     //bla bla bla
     //final del codigo
     event.target.removeEventListener(event.type, "fn_clmtrackrConverged");

 }

 document.addEventListener("clmtrackrConverged","fn_clmtrackrConverged"); 
 fn_clmtrackrConverged(event);
```

Comment: creo que lo le necesitas es usar `removeEventListener()`

Comment: @marcogomes Cómo? en donde?

Comment: Utiliza un nombre distinto a la función. Cambia el nombre al segundo parámetro del **addEventListener** y a la función asignale el mismo que has cambiado.

Comment: @sakulino aúnno funciona, el evento no se dispara, es decir se ejecuta porque lo llamo pero no se ejecuta el trigger al terminar el calculo

Comment: Debes poner la linia de **remove...** justo al final del trigger y sacarla de donde la tengas puesta.

Comment: Deberías buscarte la documentación del proyecto, en realidad no se ejecuta *n* veces, la aplicación tiene definido varios callback para distintos eventos, si tú defines la misma función para todos los eventos entonces es normal ver un funcionamiento erróneo o repetividad de las salidas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías usar **`event.target.removeEventListener(event.type, nombredelafuncion);`**, tienes que quitar el EventListener y luego ejecutas el código que quieras que se ejecute 1 sola vez.

Tu código quedaría así (te recomiendo que no uses funciones anónimas, sino haz una función y pásale el nombre al eventListener):

```
    function funcion1(event) {
        event.target.removeEventListener(event.type, "funcion1");
        //bla bla
    }

    document.addEventListener("clmtrackrNotFound","funcion1");
```

Lo mismo para cada evento.

[Documentación.](https://desarrollo-geek.net/tutoriales/javascript/eventos-de-un-tiempo-javascript/)

Comment: Gracias, disculpa la ignorancia pero no logro hacerlo funcionar. cómo hago que se dispare el evento?  funcion1() ?

Comment: Añadir un evento funciona de la siguiente manera, primero tienes que poner el evento cuando quieres que se dispare, por ejemplo "click", y luego el nombre de la función que quieres que se ejecute "funcion1", dentro de esta función es donde debes poner la linia **event.target.removeEventListener(event.type, nombredelafuncion);**.

Comment: XD, me sale un error en mi código que no me salia. Me gustaria alguna manera de eliminar los listeners asi guardando mi estructura. estoy haciendolo en angular por ejemplo quisiera que al ir a otro controlador se borraran todos los listeners..

Comment: Lo que necesitas es esto **event.target.removeEventListener(event.type, nombredelafuncion);**. De esta amnera se ejecutará el evento 1 sola vez, es la respuesta de tu pregunta. Si tienes mas dudas reformula la pregunta o haz una nueva, gracias.

Comment: mira es que si lo hago de tu manera, no funciona mi código. por que? es porque en el caso de document.addEventListener("clmtrackrConverged") se dispara cuando un calculo de la libreria finaliza, pero con tu método nunca se inicia, y si intento inicializarlo me genera error porque aún no esta listo el calculo. me hago entender?

Comment: he actualizado la pregutna a como estoy haciendolo